# how to import the binary dump sql in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Today I received a binary sql dump script `efs_bbs.sql`(MySQL 5.7),then I open it with text editor, it looks like this:

```
b#eHE-SafeNetLOCKΩA®@¨g%;ägWnímã˛~Q5åÔÔÃÄÜ]hT[ı=≥ùOf2Æ  ÔCf‹ﬂo
˛ÂŸ~È≤Ô|
î≈ª\«SlC¢%ïDúi*(âVﬁNfÛpEÍ¶«µC‡4∞ä'Ÿ~($e „˘§ÂøÔ`„ÿÆ-=iU+]ÉÒgI≥G‡]ÕﬁˇÉ4¡ÜSå≠3îxçœsùòuõB˘–\Ö%O\$Uzòo€Œ$Aaç≤GòÎ¸Æ/Zz‡’
tômj0Ò¶óÕw∑>Ô¡éüÁ±‘¡•J≥∞˘ù#Ìi   «RòUîÙJ€“R˘EÎbÍWõ+Jº$i7+.±;
®(Å¬s€ºÉï√¸+ŸñÒç…Æ
```

what should I do to import the sql to my database? I have tried this command:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\?'.
```

[image]

any other way to import? Am I doing wrong way?I also tried this way:

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 --binary-mode --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -D crmeb_merchant -o < /logs/sql/crmeb_merchant.sql
```

shows error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\�'.
```

Comment: You should try this if luck is with you it may work ```mysqlbinlog  --base64-output=decode-rows --verbose sql_file```

Comment: The `E-SafeNetLOCK` part at the start of the file shows that it’s an encrypted file. You’ll need the key and the E-SafeNet description library to gain access to the data. If nobody has the key, you *may* be able to extract it [using this tool](https://github.com/c3c/E-Safenet).

Comment: The tool last update was 5 years ago, I could not run this tool now.@matigo